# Создать select циклом

Tags: php

```
function generaStates(){
    $states = array(
        'Alabama',
        'Alaska',
        'Arizona',
        'Arkansas'
    );
}
```

Нужно сделать выпадающий список, где option - это штаты.

Comment: `<select><?php foreach($states as $state):?><option><?= $state ?></option><?php endforeach ?></select>`

Comment: @entithat section?)) select же

Comment: @DaemonHK, да-да. Механически написал))

Answer (score 0):

```
$states = array(
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas'
);

function generateStates($states){
    if(is_array($states)){
<?php
<select>
?>
        foreach($states as $key=>$state){
?>
    <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$state?></option>
<?php
            unset($key,$state);
        }
<?php
</select>
?>
    }
}
```

Однако лучше отделять код от верстки, то есть можно обойтись вообще без этой функции, просто распечатав цикл в нужном месте.

Comment: может, это во view. тут же ничего, кроме вывода не происходит :)

Comment: @splash58, согласен, но ТС явно использует ФП, а не ООП